# Google Closure: How to annotate a parameter used as a constructor

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, google-closure, webstorm

I use *require.js* for dependency management and Google Closure annotations to empower me with  autocompletion (in WebStorm / IDEA). We rely heavily on *Backbone* and develop our Javascript code in Java-like fashion - i.e. both with static and instance methods.

What remains elusive is how to properly write annotations for function arguments that are in fact classes - parameters used together with *new* keyword.

```
require(['foo'], function(Foo) {
  var bar = new Foo();
});
```

WebStorm and/or Google Closure correctly assume it is an instance of *Foo* if I annotate the parameter as follows:

```
require(['foo'],
/** @param {Foo} Foo */ 
function(Foo) {
   Foo.<cursor> <-- gives me an autocompletion for an instance of Foo
});
```

A [quick googling](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/closure-compiler-discuss/ojrIApP__O4) suggests using *function(new: Foo)* as a parameter description. This approach, however, loses autocompletion for constructor parameters and/or possible static methods the class has.

The construct I hope for should resemble this one:

```
require(['foo'],
/** @param {Type<Foo>} Foo */
function(Foo) {
   Foo.<cursor> <-- gives me an autocompletion for statics of Foo
});
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for

```
/** @param {function(new: Foo)} someConstructor */
```

You can also specify the arguments of the constructor, by doing something like

```
function(new: Foo, ArgType1, ArgType2)
```

---

The relevant passage from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=en):

> Operator Name: Function `new` Type:
>
> Syntax Example: `{function(new:goog.ui.Menu, string)}`
>
> A function that takes one parameter (a string), and creates a new instance of `goog.ui.Menu` when called with the 'new' keyword.
>
> Specifies the constructed type of a constructor.